# Please Ineed someone to convert this C code into assembly language for me

Tags: nasm

it is a code to manage contacts. that is to add, delete, search, list, edit.
i want the asm code for the c code below. my code runs on net beans in c. so i need the assembly language code for my program

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<process.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<dos.h>









struct contact

{

long ph;

char name[20],add[20],email[30];

}
list;



char query[20],name[20];

FILE *fp, *ft;

int i,n,ch,l,found;



int main()

{









main:

system("cls");    /* ************Main menu ***********************  */

printf("\n\t **** Welcome to ABIGAIL's contact Manager ****");

printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tMAIN MENU\n\t\t=====================\n\t\t[1] Add a new Contact\n\t\t[2] List all Contacts\n\t\t[3] Search for contact\n\t\t[4] Edit a Contact\n\t\t[5] Delete a Contact\n\t\t[0] Exit\n\t\t=================\n\t\t");

printf("Enter the choice:");

scanf("%d",&ch);



switch(ch)

{

case 0:

printf("\n\n\t\tAre you sure u want to exit?");

break;

/* *********************add new contacts************  */

case 1:



system("cls");

fp=fopen("contact.dll","a");

for (;;)

{ fflush(stdin);

printf("To exit enter blank space in the name input\nName (Use identical):");

scanf("%[^\n]",&list.name);

if(stricmp(list.name,"")==0 || stricmp(list.name," ")==0)

break;

fflush(stdin);

printf("Phone:");

scanf("%ld",&list.ph);

fflush(stdin);

printf("address:");

scanf("%[^\n]",&list.add);

fflush(stdin);

printf("email address:");

gets(list.email);

printf("\n");

fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp);

}

fclose(fp);

break;



/* *********************list of contacts*************************  */

case 2:

system("cls");

printf("\n\t\t================================\n\t\t\tLIST OF CONTACTS\n\t\t================================\n\nName\t\tPhone No\t    Address\t\tE-mail ad.\n=================================================================\n\n");



for(i=97;i<=122;i=i+1)

{



fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");

fflush(stdin);

found=0;

while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)==1)

{

if(list.name[0]==i || list.name[0]==i-32)

{

printf("\nName\t: %s\nPhone\t: %ld\nAddress\t: %s\nEmail\t: %s\n",list.name,

list.ph,list.add,list.email);

found++;

}

}

if(found!=0)

{printf("=========================================================== [%c]-(%d)\n\n",i-32,found);

getch();}

fclose(fp);



}



break;







/* *******************search contacts**********************  */

case 3:

system("cls");

do

{

found=0;

printf("\n\n\t..::CONTACT SEARCH\n\t===========================\n\t..::Name of contact to search: ");

fflush(stdin);

scanf("%[^\n]",&query);

l=strlen(query);

fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");



system("cls");

printf("\n\n..::Search result for '%s' \n===================================================\n",query);

while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)==1)

{

for(i=0;i<=l;i++)

name[i]=list.name[i];

name[l]='\0';

if(stricmp(name,query)==0)

{

printf("\n..::Name\t: %s\n..::Phone\t: %ld\n..::Address\t: %s\n..::Email\t:%s\n",list.name,list.ph,list.add,list.email);

found++;

if (found%4==0)

{

printf("..::Press any key to continue...");

getch();

}

}

}



if(found==0)

printf("\n..::No match found!");

else

printf("\n..::%d match(s) found!",found);

fclose(fp);

printf("\n ..::Try again?\n\n\t[1] Yes\t\t[0] No\n\t");

scanf("%d",&ch);

}while(ch==1);

break;





/* *********************edit contacts************************/

case 4:

system("cls");

fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");

ft=fopen("temp.dat","w");

fflush(stdin);

printf("..::Edit contact\n===============================\n\n\t..::Enter the name of contact to edit:");

scanf("%[^\n]",name);

while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)==1)

{

if(stricmp(name,list.name)!=0)

fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,ft);

}

fflush(stdin);

printf("\n\n..::Editing '%s'\n\n",name);

printf("..::Name(Use identical):");

scanf("%[^\n]",&list.name);

fflush(stdin);

printf("..::Phone:");

scanf("%ld",&list.ph);

fflush(stdin);

printf("..::address:");

scanf("%[^\n]",&list.add);

fflush(stdin);

printf("..::email address:");

gets(list.email);

printf("\n");

fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,ft);

fclose(fp);

fclose(ft);

remove("contact.dll");

rename("temp.dat","contact.dll");

break;





/* ********************delete contacts**********************/

case 5:

system("cls");

fflush(stdin);

printf("\n\n\t..::DELETE A CONTACT\n\t==========================\n\t..::Enter the name of contact to delete:");

scanf("%[^\n]",&name);

fp=fopen("contact.dll","r");

ft=fopen("temp.dat","w");

while(fread(&list,sizeof(list),1,fp)!=0)

if (stricmp(name,list.name)!=0)

fwrite(&list,sizeof(list),1,ft);

fclose(fp);

fclose(ft);

remove("contact.dll");

rename("temp.dat","contact.dll");

break;



default:

printf("Invalid choice");

break;

}





printf("\n\n\n..::Enter the Choice:\n\n\t[1] Main Menu\t\t[0] Exit\n");

scanf("%d",&ch);

switch (ch)

{

case 1:

goto main;





case 0:

break;



default:

printf("Invalid choice");

break;

}



return 0;

}
```

Comment: how about compiling it and looking at the assembler output (-s for gcc i think)

Comment: @pm100 : _GCC_ is `-S`

Comment: Note. Nobody here is going to do the actual work for you, but you will ge advice n how to go about it. Also - why do you want assembler? this code is clearly intended for a big OS (linux I assume)

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling, you can use the gcc `-save-temps` switch

EX: `gcc -save-temps text.c -o test.out`

and it will be saved as `test.s`

If you already have the file compiled, you can use `objdump`, which is part of the GNU binutils

EX: `objdump -d test.out`

Or redirect it to a file

EX: `objdump -d test.out > test.asm`

You can run `objdump -H` to see all the switches for the program